# how can i add multiple elements efficiently to a div tag on button click?

Tags: javascript, function, button, getelementbyid

Hey guys im building a scientific calculator in javascript and i was wondering if there was a better way of doing this because i have to do it for 50+ buttons. this is how im currently doing it in my Javascript file it works but i was thinking there must be a more efficient way doing this.

```
function percent() {
      display = document.getElementById('display')

      display = display + " %"

      document.getElementById('display').innerText = display
}
```

the id display is where i want to display the formula before the answer is given to the user.

Comment: Do you need to use pure javascript or can you use some JQuery or other libraries that will make your life easier?

Comment: i could use another library but i know javascript so thats kinda what i was using could you help me figure out how to do it with a libray

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do, need some more code to be helpful. I was just thinking that the way you have it now is a bit awkward. Did you search the web for some examples or tutorials before starting, there are a lot of these around. for example: http://ostermiller.org/calc/calculator.html or http://www.calculateforfree.com/sci2.html

Comment: im looking to do something like this http://web2.0calc.com/ but after i got the code in a file i got an error. so i was going to scrap the script and build my own and that is what i came up with and figured i would ask to see if some one had any ideas to make it better

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the object when you have to add the inner HTML of the object.

```
display = document.getElementById('display').innerHTML
```

Comment: i noticed that when i started to test other lines